# Git subscribers not creating new Project in Visual Studio solution

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, bitbucket

I have a Visual Studio 2017 solution with 8 projects in. Source control has been working fine for months with these 8 projects.

I need to add another project to the solution - I have done so on one machine and Bitbucket has added this new project - after I went to Team Explorer / Changes / Commit All.

I checked the repo on the Bitbucket website - and the new project was in the repo.

But now on another machine when I Sync (Team Explorer / Sync / Pull) - this new project is not created.

What is best practice for getting this new project propagated across all repository users?

Google searches haven't unearthed anything - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow it has started syncing new projects across bitbucket. Now sure when or why but it now works.